# Audio doesn't work on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, 19.10

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 dual boot on my Asus Zenbook UX430U, but i have some issue with sounds, because if I play something, it seems to work for a few moments, then it stops working...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, as a temporary fix I rebooted my sound driver using `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` and it seemed to work without rebooting the system.